# Proper create user account with permissions on CentOS/Apache

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I have setup a CentOS VPS to run Apache, I am having trouble with permissions when creating an account.

I have setup a virtual host host to point a domain to /home/user/public_html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
    ServerName www.user.com
    ServerAlias user.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I then added a user and make the public dir:

```
adduser user
passwd user
mkdir /home/user/public_html
```

Now when I browse this domain I get permission denied.. I can login via SSH and browse to the public directory but it does not let me create files due to permission errors.

The permission on the user dir are is 700, when I change it to 755 I get the 'Apache is installed' page, which I find weird.

I've Google'd this problem and it looks to be widespread, SELinux crops up a lot, however upon testing it is already disabled on my server:

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual I worked it out 30 seconds after creating this post. I was creating the folder in the same SSH session, ie.. under the root user, so even though the /home/user folder belonged to 'user' the public_html folder belonged to root.

Letting the 'user' create the public_html folder allowed me to work within it and of course the domain is now serving the correct page.